# Canvas variable not updating when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, refresh

See link: http://jndgn.com/colortheory/bezold.html

When clicking the 'Bigger Stripes' link in the nav I'm attempting to simply update the number of colored stripes in the canvas below it. The variable 'stripeNum' is set at 100 and when clicked should change to 20 via:

```
$(function(){
  $("#stripes").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(stripeNum == 100) {
        stripeNum = 20;
    } else {
        stripeNum = 100;
    }       
  });
})
```

...but when clicked, no action occurs. Do I somehow need to get the canvas to update itself? A bit of an HTML5 rookie here. Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmurE/1/) attached for easier code transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-draw the canvas, as well as clearing it when you do this. You could simply make this adjustment and you'd be good:

First, wrap the canvas drawing you have in a function:

```
var contextFill = function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear on draw
  for (var i = 0; i < stripeNum + 1; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0, i * canvas.height / stripeNum, canvas.width, canvas.height / (2 * stripeNum));
    context.fillStyle = randomColor;
    context.fill();
   }
}
```

Then, call `contextFill()` on document ready. The only addition I made to the above is `context.clearRect`, to clear the canvas.

Finally, also call it when your bigger stripes is called, e.g.:

```
...
if (stripeNum == 100) {
     stripeNum = 20;
} else {
     stripeNum = 100;
}    
contextFill();
```

If you want to update canvas on window resize, you can watch the `resize` event on the window. The downside is it can occur many times depending on how the user is resizing. You can use a library like [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs) to ensure that the function only is called every `N` milliseconds. For example:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', _.debounce(function() {
     contextFill();
}, 500));
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Quickest, simplest, and most straightforward response I've ever received. Thanks a bunch! Cheers!

Comment: I've also never been able to figure out a proper way to update the canvas when the window is resized. Would it be possible to call `contextFill()` on window resize?

Comment: @JohnDuggan With vanilla JS, you can add an event listener to window resize, like so: `window.addEventListener('resize', function() { contextFill(); })` -- The downside of this, is that it will occur way too many times to be good for performance if the user is fiddling with the size. The simplest solution for that is to use a utility belt library like [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs) and use `_.debounce`. I've updated my answer with an example

Comment: Didn't seem to be having any luck implementing the resize function with or without using lodash, until I realized that contextFill() needs to include the following: `canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerHeight;` in order for it to want to fill the space. Thanks so much again for your help.

Comment: Ah yes, good catch! Makes sense to collect the latest width/height after resize.